# pass an objective-c object to javaScript function

Tags: ios, objective-c

Pass an customed Objective-C object to JSContext,so we can call object's method in js,but i want to pass it to a javaScript function then in this function I can call that object's method.

```
function myJs(para){
    para.myMethod();
    //this para is an customed objective-c object which had implemented JSExport protocol
}
// call that js function
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJs(%@)", para]];
```

However it doesn't work, so is there any way to implement it?

Comment: do you want to call objective c method from javascript?

Comment: Yes,when i pass A,it can call A's myMethod().when i pass B,it can call B's myMethod(). call myMethod() dynamically,not call it directly.Hope you can understand me.

Comment: But actually, you cannot call Objective-C methods directly from Javascript. But it can be done indirectly through `web​View:​should​Start​Load​With​Request:​navigation​Type:​` method

Comment: Please take on look my answer how can it be done in an indirect way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to call Objective-C methods from javascript directly, but you can achieve this by calling an URL from javascript and capture it using `webView:shouldStart​Load​With​Request:​navigation​Type:​` delegate method.

Just make an URL redirection from javascript and catch it in delegate please check below code

```
  // This function is called on all location change :
  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 
          shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
          navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    // Intercept custom location change, URL begins with "js-call:"
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"js-call:"]) {

      // Extract the selector name from the URL
      NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
      NSString *function = [components objectAtIndex:1];

      // Call the given selector
      [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(functionName)];

      // Cancel the location change
      return NO;
    }

    // Accept this location change
    return YES;

  }
```

Here is the excellent [tutorial](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/) that helps to do it

Comment: Thank you for your help.